# How to load extension for Chrome in remote selenium using golang?

Tags: selenium, go, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have selenium in docker container(selenoid from aerocube) and selenium library for golang from tebeka.

I can't find any examples that show how to run chrome in a remote selenium with the extension (literally only for go)

I even found function in library which do it, but I did not found example of code where It was used.
(https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/tebeka/selenium@v0.9.9/chrome#Capabilities.AddExtension)

```
caps := selenium.Capabilities{"browserName": "chrome", "browserVersion": "103.0"}

driver, err := selenium.NewRemote(caps, "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("create selenium session error: %v\n", err)
    return
}
defer driver.Quit()
driver.Get("https://www.google.com/")
driver.Close()
```

Answer (score 2):

I want to use the modheader extention, but I get the same question, and i solved it.

**Step 1: Get your chrome extention (.crx) file**

In my case, i find the modheader document,and get download link from the page.

https://docs.modheader.com/advanced/selenium-webdriver

Download the .crx file to you project.
[the .crx download page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TflXf.png)

Download link
https://github.com/modheader/modheader_selenium/raw/main/chrome-modheader/modheader.crx

Note: Web browser maybe block the download by policy, use the "wget" command get the
file.

[block by browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0zd1.png)

[wget the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vD9h2.png)

If you want to get other extention , use the follow CRX Extracti/Downloader can help you.

[CRX Extracti link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/crx-extractordownloader/ajkhmmldknmfjnmeedkbkkojgobmljda)
[CRX Extracti/Downloader webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Vyvp.png)

**Step 2: Use the Code loding the extention**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/tebeka/selenium"
    "github.com/tebeka/selenium/chrome"
)

const (
    port = 8080
)

func main() {

    opts := []selenium.ServiceOption{
        // Enable fake XWindow session.
        // selenium.StartFrameBuffer(),
        selenium.Output(os.Stderr), // Output debug information to STDERR
    }

    _, err := selenium.NewChromeDriverService("../your_driver_path/chromedriver.exe", port, opts...)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    
    caps := selenium.Capabilities{"browserName": "chrome"}
    var cap_ext chrome.Capabilities

    // add your extention by crx file
    cap_ext.AddExtension("./modheader.crx")
    caps.AddChrome(cap_ext)

    wd, err := selenium.NewRemote(caps, fmt.Sprintf("http://127.0.0.1:%d/wd/hub", port))

    // Using api to setting modheader

    // add header
    wd.Get("https://webdriver.modheader.com/add?test=ModHeader%20Test")

}
```

**Step 3: Setting the extention**

Modheader extention supply api to setting.

Example :

```
wd.Get("https://webdriver.modheader.com/add?test=ModHeader%20Test")
```

Step 4: Result

[Loading and setting extention successful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiXGY.png)

I hope that I can help. Good Luck.